# GWT MVP Navigation Sidebar

Tags: gwt

I am writing a web application using GWT, and following the [MVP tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) on the GWT website (i.e. using [`History`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory) for navigation).

I am a bit confused as to the best way of having a side-bar for navigation (i.e. clicking a navigation link changes content in main window. See below)

```
--------------------
|     |            |
| nav |   main     |
|     |    window  |
|     |            |
|     |            |
--------------------
```

One potential way I see of doing this is to declare two `<div>` tags in the HTML for navigation and content. For example:

```
@Override
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {

    ...

    if (token.equals("navigation")) {
        presenter = new NavigationPresenter(rpcService, eventBus, new NavigationView());
        presenter.go(RootPanel.get("navigation"));
    }

    ...

    if (token.equals("content")) {
        presenter = new ContentPresenter(rpcService, eventBus, new ContentView());
        presenter.go(RootPanel.get("content"));
    }

    ...
}
```

I am unsure if this is the best way of approaching this. (I guess bi-directional communication between the navigation panel and the content window could be done through an `EventBus`? Is this method flexible when it comes to changing the UI (e.g. for mobile sites))

I was wondering what people would suggest is the best way of going about this. I have read around and often land on discussions about [Activities and Places](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces), but as I understand it these are somewhat different to MVP architecture (activities and places is useful for [browser history management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193909/model-view-presenter-with-google-web-toolkit-gwt), although I think my use of `History` covers that (?))

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right: `Activies and Places` are about history and navigation management, a framework inside `GWT`. `MVP` is simply an architectural design pattern. You can achieve `MVP` using such framework as shown in the article you linked.

In your sample, you can do as you say, but I'd make each view a (lazy) singleton in order to avoid any potentially expensive re-creation. Personally I don't like this way, you end up defining your `Display`s in terms of (so many) `HasXxx` interfaces.

I think that if history management is important, choosing `Activities and Places` is almost a no-brainer (at least for me, and at least to define the skeleton of the app). [Here](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-activities) you can find a really good article to get you started. And you will see how common your use case is: you have to define displayed regions (you navigation and main areas) that will react (thanks to the activity managers) on place change and create/restart the activities that will in turn update the UI. This way you achieve some sort of app-wide `MVP` in which the presenters are the activities.

As far as `MVP` is concerned, there is no *best way* of doing that: [part 1](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture), [part 2](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2) and [MVP with A&P](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) are simply different ways to achieve the same goal: separation between presentation and business logic, as well as pure junit testing. Simply choose what you like. See [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/f20FbM04usU/discussion) post on groups for reference.

Hope that get you started.

Comment: First off @Andrea Boscolo is definitely right : I have studied history management under every angle my modest brain could possibly figure out, and Acitivities & Places is your best way to achieve history mapping without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The only downside to it is the way tokens are generated by  PlaceHistoryMapper @WithTokenizers : URLs are ugly IMO, place prefix separated by ":" and then parameters.

I have implemented "Self tokenizing" places, that generated URLs like : "www.myapp.com/#/placeprefix/param1=value1&param2=value2

instead of GWT's standard : www.myapp.com/#placeprefix:anythingelseinthetoken

... That's just because I'm a URL maniac probably

Answer (score 0):

For my apps, I use a ClientFactory just like in the GWT doc, with singleton for Views.

That way, the application structure (which includes the menu) is also a singleton referenced in the ClientFactory, so every other view can virtually access it directly through its interface.

For example some view might push some image in the header, hide the menu to display a video, or whatever you need. Most of the time, the app's structure does not need a separate activity/place to "persist" its state in the history stack...

I know most people don't like to have views calling each other, and so do I, the only exception is the app's structure view, which is kind of a specific one : it has a presenter which is not an activity, and the view itself is permanently displayed.

Communicating between your app structure and other views with notifications will make your app a spaghetti bowl IMHO. I have worked with frameworks like PureMVC which rely a lot on events/notifications to communicate between view, and the separation has a steep cost : maintainability and code readability.